# speed of decoding and encoding json in perl

Tags: json, performance, perl, decode, encode

I'am working on a small perl script. And I store the data using JSON.

I decode the JSON string using `from_json` an encode with `to_json`.

To be more specific:

The data scale could be something like **100,000** items in a hash

The data is stored in a file in the disk.

So to decode it, I'll have to read it from the disk first

---

And my question is:

There is a huge difference in the speed between the decoding and encoding process.

The encoding process seems to be much faster than the decoding process.

And I wonder what makes that difference ?

Comment: do you have JSON::XS installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON (the module) is not a parser/encoder. It's merely a front-end for JSON::XS (very fast) or JSON::PP (not so much). JSON will use JSON::XS if it's installed, but defaults to JSON::PP if it's not. You might see very different numbers depending on whether you have JSON::XS installed or not.

I could see a Perl parser (like JSON::PP) having varying performances for encoding and decoding because it's hard to write something optimal because of all the overhead, but the difference should be much smaller using JSON::XS.

It might still be a bit slower to decode using JSON::XS because of all the memory blocks it has to allocate. Allocating memory is a relatively expensive process, and it needs to be done fare more time when decoding than when encoding. For example, a Perl string consists of a three memory blocks (scalar head, scalar body and the string buffer itself). When encoding, allocating memory is only done when the output buffer needs to be enlarged.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing is much more computationally expensive than formatting.

`from_json` has to parse the json structures and convert them into perl data structures, `to_json` merely has to iterate through the data structure and "print" out each item in a formatted way.

Parsing is a complex topic that still is the focus of CS theory work. However at the base level, parsing is a 2 step operation. You need to parse the input stream for tokens and then validate the sequence of tokens as a valid statement in the language. Encoding is on the other hand a single step operation, you already know it's valid, you simply have to convert it to the representation.

Comment: Could explain ** arsing is much more computationally expensive than formatting ** to me? Cause I thought formatting is just the inverse process of parsing.

Comment: And division is the inverse of multiplication, but one is more computationally expensive than the other.

Comment: Re "Parsing is much more computationally expensive than formatting", That's not true. Encoding is basically a switch statement keyed on variable type. Decoding is basically a switch statement keyed on the next token in the stream. The two processes are virtually identical, especially for JSON.

Comment: Re "*Parsing is much more computationally expensive than formatting*", Generally, yes, but not here. The `switch` for parsing JSON is quite small. much smaller than the number of kinds of Perl values the encoder needs to handle.